# How to execute command on list of file names in a file?

Tags: linux, rm

I have listed the names of the files which are to be deleted into a file. How can I pass the file to `rm` command so that it should delete them one by one.

Comment: See [FAQ 001 on Greg's Wiki](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001)...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you have one file per line, one way to do it is:

```
tr '\n' '\0' < list_of_files_to_be_deleted.txt | xargs -0 -r rm --
```

The file list is given as input to the `tr` command which changes the file separator from linefeed to the null byte and the `xargs` command reads files separated by null bytes on input and launches the rm command with the files appended as arguments.

Comment: I'd also suggest using `rm --` instead of just `rm`, so that filenames which may start with dash would not be treated as `rm` parameters.

Comment: It didn't work buddy........

        tr: extra operand `monu.txt'
        Try `tr --help' for more information.
        rm: missing operand
        Try `rm --help' for more information.


........This is all wat i am able to see

Comment: Did you perhaps miss the < before the filename?

Comment: I improved the xargs command a bit also - added -- according to @artyom 's suggestion and added -r to make sure it doesn't run rm if there are no files to remove.

Answer (score 7):

The above answer is fine in that it goes to great lengths to handle filesnames with spaces and "strange caracters". But the simplest way, if the file names are sane, is just (warning, bashism!):

```
rm $(< /the/file/with/names)
```

For regular shell:

```
rm `cat /the/file/with/names`
```